# how can I access to serialport properties in another form?

Tags: c#

I have a serial port and button is in my main form.I want that, when I click on button then it open another form and set serial port properties.for example stopbits and baudrate and ..... How can I access to serialport properties in form2? How can I write cods?.I Write this code

```
 //Form1

    public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  public SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1",
      9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
.
.
.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }


}
// Form2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               Form1 frm = new Form1();
               frm.port.BaudRate=9600;


    }
}
```

but this cod can't change BaudRate in Form1.
can help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Where did you stuck, what problems are you facing?

Comment: "how can I access to serialport properties in form2" you need to pass the `SerialPort` object to the form2. Its like asking "how can my brother access my cell phone?" the answer would be you need to give your brother your cell phone... :)

Comment: Serial ports are special, they cannot be shared.  Or in other words, there can only ever be one SerialPort instance for a port.  So that gives you a good reason to declare the variable `static`.  Now it is dead simple, just `Form1.port`

Comment: thank you very much.so is this true?                                                    public static SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1",
      9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);